# Log.html only showing the passed test cases when using the "pabot --testlevelsplit Tests/demo.robot" command

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to learn robot & facing two confusions(m a total noob) .Pretty sure I am making a rookie mistake & would appreciate some help .

1)Every time I execute the tests using the "pabot --testlevelsplit Tests/demo.robot" command, the log.html  doesn't show the failed test case (in this case: Fill the login form and select "Teacher" from the User option) even though the terminal output shows it as failed.

2. The same test case however passes when I run them individually and log.html shows 3 passed test cases.
   [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS2BB.png)[Log showing only the 2 passed cases
   [terminal showing only 2 passed test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdeGx.png)
   [all the test cases passed and showing up in logs when executed using the ".robot /Test/demo.robot" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQCDh.png)

Comment: I can't see any major problems in your code sample. The only tiny improvement would be to replace `Task Setup` and `Task Teardown` with `Test Setup` and `Test Teardown`. It should have no real effect but makes their purpose cleaner. Does your terminal output show that pabot is running missing test? Have you tried running pabot with `--verbose` parameter?

Comment: Thanks@Pekka,running pabot with --verbose parameter solved the issue. The tests ran without failing and the terminal output showed 3 tests passed,0 skipped ! I still wish I knew why the failed test case in question never showed up in the log html file while using pabot  --testlevelsplit .  I really appreciate your help !